# enabledHours in bootstrap-datetimepicker-3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm working with http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ . I know this isn't supported anymore but I am also working with rails, and this just makes my life so much easier. 
What I'm trying to do is set enabled hours to a range of values. Here's what I have:

```
scheduleHandle.onclick = function (){
    $('#schedule_date_time_of_class').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
        sideBySide: true,
        enabledHours: [[moment().hour(14).minutes(0), moment().hour(17).minutes(0)]]
    });
};
```

Here's the error I get:

> ```
> Uncaught Tried 24 times to find a valid date
> picker.enabledHours @ bootstrap-datetimepicker.self-9bf8b50ba86095fb5caaadd1ee11eaf661b3f4879f3ea5263d541e9804fd7b15.js?body=1:2188
> (anonymous) @ bootstrap-datetimepicker.self-9bf8b50ba86095fb5caaadd1ee11eaf661b3f4879f3ea5263d541e9804fd7b15.js?body=1:1430
> each @ jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:377
> picker.options @ bootstrap-datetimepicker.self-9bf8b50ba86095fb5caaadd1ee11eaf661b3f4879f3ea5263d541e9804fd7b15.js?body=1:1428
> dateTimePicker @ bootstrap-datetimepicker.self-9bf8b50ba86095fb5caaadd1ee11eaf661b3f4879f3ea5263d541e9804fd7b15.js?body=1:2252
> (anonymous) @ bootstrap-datetimepicker.self-9bf8b50ba86095fb5caaadd1ee11eaf661b3f4879f3ea5263d541e9804fd7b15.js?body=1:2285
> each @ jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:371
> each @ jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1:138
> $.fn.datetimepicker @ bootstrap-datetimepicker.self-9bf8b50ba86095fb5caaadd1ee11eaf661b3f4879f3ea5263d541e9804fd7b15.js?body=1:2280
> scheduleHandle.onclick @ 51:150
> ```

I have no clue where I'm going wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of integers to [`enabledHours`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#enabledhours), setting the hours you want to disable.

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#schedule_date_time_of_class').datetimepicker({
  inline: true,
  sideBySide: true,
  enabledHours: [ 14, 15, 16 ]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class='input-group date' id='schedule_date_time_of_class'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```